# <__main__.CloudTravel object at 0x000000D30F609828> is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

**.py**

```
a = (0,0,70)
b = (90,0,45)
c = ("1 2","0 2","0 1")
d = 0
e = 1

class Travel(object):

    def trip(self,latitude,longitude,canTravel,origin,destination):
        self.latitude    = latitude
        self.longitude   = longitude
        self.canTravel   = canTravel
        self.origin      = origin
        self.destination = destination
        print(latitude)
        print(longitude)
        print(origin)
        print(destination)
        print(canTravel)
        for c in canTravel:
            print(c)
        pass


c = Travel()
c.trip(a,b,c,d,e)
```

**output**

```
(0, 0, 70)
(90, 0, 45)
0
1
<__main__.Travel object at 0x000000E836D25898>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\shortestpath.py", line 26, in <module>
    c.trip(a,b,c,d,e)
  File ".\shortestpath.py", line 20, in trip
    for c in canTravel:
TypeError: 'Travel' object is not iterable
```

I want to pass the tuple of string **("1 2","0 2","0 1")** to the trip function, and want to iterate over it.

How do I iterate over the <**main**.Travel object at 0x000000E836D25898>

Comment: You *didn't* pass your tuple to `.trip()`; you overwrote the variable `c` with the `Travel()` object prior to the call.  Choose a different name for one of those variables.

Comment: worked @jasonharper. Thank You.